# What is the structure sheaf of an scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm currently reading chapter II of Hartshorne's algebraic geometry and there defines structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ of an affine scheme  $X = \mathrm{Spec}\ A$ .
    For  each open set $U \subseteq X$, define $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ to be the set of functions$$s: U \rightarrow \coprod_{\mathfrak{p} \in U} A_{\mathfrak{p}}$$
such that $s(\mathfrak{p}) \in A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ for each $\mathfrak{p}$, and such that $s$ is locally a quotient of elements of $A$, that is, for each $\mathfrak{p} \in U$, there is some neighborhood $V_{\mathfrak{p}}$ of $\mathfrak{p}$ with $V_{\mathfrak{p}} \subseteq U$ and elements $a,f \in A$ such that for each $\mathfrak{q} \in V$ and $f \notin \mathfrak{q}$, $s(\mathfrak{q} )= a/f$ in $A_{\mathfrak{q}}$.

My question is :
How can we define structure sheaf of a scheme which is not an affine scheme i.e. when $X$$\neq$ $\mathrm{Spec}\ A$ , what will be the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ on X.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a scheme is a locally ringed space $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ which is locally isomorphic to affine schemes.  So, the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ of $X$ is part of the data of what it means for $X$ to be a scheme; it is already provided if you say $X$ is a scheme.